# Just retrieve the first result of an xml file

Tags: android, xml-parsing, sax

I'm trying to retrieve the first result of a search. The search returns a xml file, and I'm treating that xml with sax parser.
In fact, I'd like to parse the xml file, and just stop when I've treated the first result of that search.

ie : I'd like to parse this file : http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release?query=barcode:606949062927 and just retrieve the first result (the album from Eminem). But when I'm using my code, I store the last result (the album from Daniel Swain), which I don't want. So this would be a lot better (less time consuming) if I could just stop the parsing after the first result.

I think this is possible by setting a boolean `firstResult`, and set it to true when I've finished to treat the first result, but I find it really dirty. Do you think there is another way to do it ?

Here is part of my code :

```
public DataMusic parseBarcode(InputStream is) {

    final DataMusic resultAlbum = new DataMusic();

    RootElement root = new RootElement(ATOM_NAMESPACE,"metadata");
    Element releaseList=root.getChild(ATOM_NAMESPACE,"release-list");
    Element release = releaseList.getChild(ATOM_NAMESPACE,"release");
    Element title = release.getChild(ATOM_NAMESPACE,"title");
    Element artistCredit = release.getChild(ATOM_NAMESPACE,"artist-credit");
    Element nameCredit = artistCredit.getChild(ATOM_NAMESPACE,"name-credit");
    Element artist = nameCredit.getChild(ATOM_NAMESPACE,"artist");
    Element artistName = artist.getChild(ATOM_NAMESPACE, "name");
    releaseList.setStartElementListener(new StartElementListener() {
        @Override
        public void start(Attributes attributes) {
            if(attributes.getValue("count").equals(null) || attributes.getValue("count").equals("") || attributes.getValue("count").equals("0")) {
                resultAlbum.setMBId(null);
                resultAlbum.setAlbumName(null);
                resultAlbum.setArtistName(null);
                Log.w(TAG_MB, "Album was not found on MB. count=" + attributes.getValue("count") +".");
            }

        }
    });
    release.setStartElementListener(new StartElementListener() {
        @Override
        public void start(Attributes attributes) {
            resultAlbum.setMBId(attributes.getValue("id"));
            Log.v(TAG_MB, "Album found with id=" + attributes.getValue("id"));
        }

    });
    title.setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener() {
        @Override
        public void end(String body) {
            Log.v(TAG_MB, "Album name set to " + body);
            resultAlbum.setAlbumName(body);
        }

    });
    artistName.setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener() {
        @Override
        public void end(String body) {
            Log.v(TAG_MB, "Album artist name set to " + body);
            resultAlbum.setArtistName(body);
        }           
    });
    try {
        Log.v(TAG_MB, "Starting parsing data...");
        Xml.parse(is, Xml.Encoding.UTF_8, root.getContentHandler());
        Log.v(TAG_MB, "Finished parsing. Returning album with MBID=" + resultAlbum.getMBId() + " and name=" + resultAlbum.getAlbumName()) ;
        return resultAlbum; 
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        Log.e(TAG_MB + "_SAXException", "SAXException with MusicBrainz");
        Log.e(LOGCAT_TAG + "_SAXException",e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w(TAG_MB+ "_IOException", "The HTTP Request wasn't good. Either 403 error, or the album wasn't found on LASTFM");
        Log.w(LOGCAT_TAG+ "_IOException", "" + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return null;
```

}

Comment: I'm not a big fan of parsing or writing XML parsers.  Call me lazy but json is a bit easier. Take a look at this example on converting xml to json.  Maybe this will feel more natural to you too. 
http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/278-how-to-convert-xml-to-json-in-java/

Comment: Hum, since this feed is also available in json, maybe I should consider parsing it as json. Is json really better than xml ?

Comment: to me it is. Android has pretty good yet simple support for json. Also the data payload is less (no end tags needed). If you need to get super fancy there is always the jackson json parser. http://jackson.codehaus.org/

Comment: If you want to just read one part of the XML, use an XMLPullParser

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the only thing better than having the boolean `firstResult` would be to have a single instance of `DataMusic` object. You can have a null check of the application wide single instance `DataMusic` object right at the top of the function. If you find it `null` you can be sure that the parsing of XML is happening for the first time and you can go ahead and initialize and set the values for the object. Next time when you check and find that the single instance object of `DataMusic` is not null you may conclude that the XML has been parsed and values have been set.

Hope this explanation helps.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood, but what you suggest is to let `resultAlbum` to null, and check if it is set to null and then initialize it and set the values I need. But I can't initialize it because it's a final variable, I can just refer to the getters and setters from DataMusic. In fact, this is the same problem with that boolean `firstResult`, I'd need to declare a boolean array so i can modify it, or define my own Object.

Comment: What I meant to say was have a Single Application Wide Instance of the object `DataMusic`. If you have a single instance it will only be initialized once. And that first time initialization would be in the function `parseBarcode()`. So the first time you check this Single Instance object you would find it as `null`(since it has not yet been initialized), but the second time you will find it `not null` because you have already initialized it and has set its values during the first parsing. I hope I am making some sense to you?

Comment: Alright. I'm getting your point. But I think I might have misdescribed my problem. I don't want to check if it is the first time `parseBarcode` is called. I want to get just the first result included inside the xml (which returned many). IE, in that xml : http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release?query=barcode:606949062927 I'd want to get the Eminem album ( what I called first result), not the Daniel Swain's one. Is it clearer ? If it is, I'll edit my question.

Comment: Your question didn't seem to correctly convey your problem. But your latest comment does. So as you suggested, go ahead and edit your question.